# How to make CMake generated INSTALL be generated when selecting "Build solution"

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution generated by CMake. CMake created a "INSTALL" project that copies all the files I requested (using Cmake's install command in my CMakeLists.txt files).

This "INSTALL" project is skipped when I request a full solution build

I tried to add `set_target_properties(INSTALL PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL FALSE)` but this reports `set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: INSTALL`.

How can I make "INSTALL" be generated by default? I'd like the checkbox surrounded in red in screenshot below to be enabled automatically:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD.html):

```
set(CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD 1)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After some checking, it seems that there is a single common function that sets which projects are part of default build.

[`cmGlobalVisualStudio7Generator::IsPartOfDefaultBuild`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/44c978a2dab96b44ed2dd7470f532c4aa4c7da7c/Source/cmGlobalVisualStudio7Generator.cxx)

Here is the part that does the check:

```
const std::string propertyName =
          "CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_" + *t + "_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD";
// inspect CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_<*t>_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD properties
```

So as was mentioned in Florian's answer, you should be able to use `CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD` as well any custom project using

`set(CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_<custom project name>_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD 1)`

Comment: That's interesting. I've given it a try with projects included via [`include_external_msproject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_external_msproject.html), but it unfortunately didn't work. Looking at the code you have linked I would say it only works for `GLOBAL_TARGET` type of targets (`INSTALL`, `RUN_TESTS`, `PACKAGE`)

Answer (score 2):

Moreover, the variable can be added as an option on cmake launch from command line.
For VS 2017:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD=ON ..
```